# How to get the digest of an asset in Rails4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

In Rails3 you could get the current digest for application.js as follows:

```
Rails.application.config.assets.digests['application.js'].split('-').last.split('.').first
```

How can this be achieved in Rails4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the following works in Rails4:

```
Rails.application.assets.find_asset('application.js').digest
```